# String matching with boolean logic

Tags: java, regex, parsing, grammar

I want to create something that will determine whether multiple tokens are contained within a given string using boolean logic.

For example: "(foo AND bar) OR fubar" would evaluate to true on the string "foo blah bar blah" because the string contains foo AND it contains bar. It would also evaluate to true on any string containing "fubar" because that condition is met and it is an OR statement. The regular expression that I thought of for that logic statement would be:

```
((?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)|(?=.*fubar))
```

The only operators I need to support are "AND", "OR", and "NOT". Are there any existing libraries or projects that perform this functionality (preferably that run on the JVM)? I have looked into creating this on my own by parsing the boolean logic into a regular expression using positive and negative lookaheads as mentioned above but would like to know if there is a better way/a library that does this.

Edited for clarity.

Comment: First step would be to pick up a standard java book, second would be to look up how to compare strings here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Is `(foo AND bar) OR` a match?

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear.  Are you trying to write a function that takes the `String` `"(foo AND bar) OR fubar"` as input and returns something like `"(foo.*bar)|fubar"` as output?

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII I know how to write Java code and I know how to compare strings. That is not what I am asking to do. I am asking to be able to programmatically check if a boolean condition is met given a string of tokens and operators.

Comment: @ajb Yes, I'm sorry for the confusion. That is one example of how I would like it to work out.

Comment: @Alex Parsing an input expression is too big a problem to answer here; try looking for information on "operator precedence parsers" (there's a Wikipedia page for it).  If you can get your parser to build a tree, it shouldn't be difficult to write a recursive routine to process the tree to build your regex.  Sorry, I don't know what libraries would help with this.

Comment: Your regex works, but please note that you don't need the outer parentheses.

Comment: @ajb Thank you, I was working on the recursive routine to build to regex earlier but I was wondering if there was a better way/a library. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this; couldn't you just use

```
if ((string.contains("foo") && string.contains("bar")) || string.contains("fubar")) {
    // match found
}
```